# Drop Down List binded, auto select an Item/make a specific Item first

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

i have a drop down list on my page with Countries, here is my code behind where i grab the ddl id, and bind my datasource:

```
DropDownList ddlSalary = (DropDownList)this.FindControl(MyControls.CountryDDL);
if (ddlSalary != null)
{
ddlSalary.DataSource = MyMethods.LoadCountries();
ddlSalary.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlSalary.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlSalary.DataBind();
}
```

My Countries ive written in are Alphabetical. But id like the option to move a specific one to the top of the List, or perhaps an Auto-Select. Example 'United Kingdom' is first in the list
What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this logic is better suited to be placed in your service/model provider (MyMethods.LoadCountries(); ).

Something like:

```
public static List<Country> LoadOrderedCountries(){
     var orderedCounteries = MyMethods.LoadCountries(); 
     orderedCounteries .Sort(); // Just to make sure alphabetical order, assuming that Country implements IComparable
     var defaultCountry = Country.GetDefault();
     orderedCounteries .Remove(defaultCountry);
     orderedCounteries .Insert(0, defaultCountry);

     return orderedCounteries ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick & dirty way to do it with SQL. I prefer to do it at database level

1. What I am doing is selecting the items you want first in the list
2. Union ALL with items you want in the list in ascending order by name excluding the ones in my first query
3. Results are with first Item at top irrespective of 2nd query

   > select * from ( (select Empcode,Empname from
   >   mySchema.Employees where EmpCode not in (90) ) UNION ALL
   >
   > select EmpCode,EmpName from mySchema.Employeeswhere
   >   EmpCode=90 order by EmpName) as z
4. You ca also set the value selected on pageLoad as

> ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue="90";

Answer (score -1):

I normally do this in the databound event

```
 DropDownList ddlSalary = (DropDownList)this.FindControl(MyControls.CountryDDL);
        if (ddlSalary != null)
        {
        ddlSalary.DataSource = MyMethods.LoadCountries();
        ddlSalary.DataValueField = "Value";
        ddlSalary.DataTextField = "Text";
        ddlSalary.DataBind();
        ddlSalary.DataBound += ddlSalary_DataBound;
        }
  protected void ddlSalary_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      ListItem MovingItem =  ddlSalary.Items.FindByValue("yourvalue");
      ddlSalary.Items.Remove(MovingItem);
      ddlSalary.Items.Insert(0, MovingItem);
  }
```

Edit: this method is more suited to adding an a "Other" type option, which is not supplied by your datasource. Amby's solution is better than this.

Answer (score -1):

After databinding your datasource, you can just sort the `ListItems`

A better way to do so is to do the sorting in your datasource (you haven't supplied enough information regarding where are you getting the data from)

```
private void SortDDL(ref DropDownList objDDL)
{
    ArrayList textList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList valueList = new ArrayList();


    foreach (ListItem li in objDDL.Items)
    {
        textList.Add(li.Text);
    }    

    textList.Sort();


    foreach (object item in textList)
    {
        string value = objDDL.Items.FindByText(item.ToString()).Value;
        valueList.Add(value);
    }
    objDDL.Items.Clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < textList.Count; i++)
    {
        ListItem objItem = new ListItem(textList[i].ToString(), valueList[i].ToString());
        objDDL.Items.Add(objItem);
    }
 }
```